# An counterexample of Hahn-Banach theorem in a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Problem : Give an example of a TVS $\mathcal{X}$ that is not locally convex and a subspace $\mathcal{Y}$ of $\mathcal{X}$ such that there is a continuous linear functional $f$ on $\mathcal{Y}$ with no continuous extension to $\mathcal{X}$

I think this problem means that Hahn-Banach theorem ( LCS version ) may not hold in a TVS.

But I can't find a counterexample..

Comment: $L^p$ with $0<p<1$

Comment: It's a standard result that $L^p[0,1]$ has trivial dual for $0 < p < 1$. Now apply the hint I gave in my answer.

Comment: Ahh.. i understand it Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Do you know of a TVS with trivial dual space? Then take any non-zero linear functional on a one-dimensional subspace.